# Installing to Ubuntu 17.04 using flash drive from old dual booted system. Can I still dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu

A little background.  I had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a Windows 10 dual boot.  I tried the command-line upgrade. After command

> do-release-upgrade

my computer began to update for a while,  then restarted.  After restart, the login screen is stuck in an infinite freeze.  After numerous attempts at fixing via the terminal by referencing Stack Exchange, I decided that it would be simply easier to do a fresh install through a USB drive.  (most of the files I need are already backed up).  Most of the advice regarding fixing the infamous frozen login loop hasn't worked so far.

My question is, if I install Ubuntu 17.04 via flash drive, will I still be able to dual boot to Windows 10.  And if yes, is there additional instructions I need to ensure that Windows 10 will boot?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes to all, provided you know what you're doing. Not really sure about that because if you knew you wouldn't need to ask. How were the OSes installed, UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: Legacy for both.  And you are right, for the most part I am learning and am effectively in "newb" territory.  The first installation of Ubuntu went smoothly.  The latest, not so much.

Comment: Always prefer UEFI when available and only old PCs are BIOS. But in any case you can install the new Ubuntu with "something else" and select the old partitions. It should install as before, reinstall and update Grub (in the MBR), detecting both Ubuntu and Windows.